# Unable to post sqlite records to server

Tags: java, android, json, sqlite

**i am getting the following error .. 
cannot convert Beans to ArrayList(String)...**

*i have One Beans file ....(Gettter and setters)*

```
 ArrayList<Beans> contactList = new ArrayList<Beans>();

 List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();


        for (int i = 0 ; i <contactList.size(); i++) {

            List<String> list =  contactList.get(i);
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", list.get(1)));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("city", list.get(2)));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("gender",list.get(3)));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("bloodgroup",list.get(4)));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("age",list.get(5)));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("emailAddress",list.get(6)));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("contactNumber",list.get(7)));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("imagePath",list.get(8)));

              //Post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(
                    _URL, "POST", params);
```

Answer (score 0):

`contactList.get(i)` will return you `Beans`. You are trying to assign the `Beans` object to `List`. You need to do

instead of this

```
List<String> list =  contactList.get(i);
```

replace with

```
Beans list =  contactList.get(i);
```

Comment: Well, then you have to create an object of type Beans.